# Is there a way to find which script/function changes the attribute of an element?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have the problem that on a website some script modifies the href attribute of the link tags. So for example:

```
<a href="#footer">go to footer</href>
```

becomes:

```
<a href="#footer?foobar">go to footer</a>
```

I tried to use Chrome Developer Tools to find it's source but wasn't successful. When inspecting element and using right click --> break on ... the attribute was already changed. When setting a breakpoint on dom content loaded and combining it with the mentioned setting nothing is listed.

There are way too many scripts and searching for `attr('href')` or `attr("href")` didn't help either.

The "visual event" plugin for chrome only shows interaction events for elements - so it wasn't of much help in this case.

How could I debug this? I know that there are event listeners for "DOMAttrModified" which could give me the value before and after the change. But that's what I already know. Is it possible to originate the source of the script or that function that is causing the change?

Comment: It could also be a plugin. Try visiting the site in a pluginfree browser

Comment: do you have access to the core files? depending on how the site is architectured, i would try removing scripts until the issue no longer appears -- at least then it'll give you an idea of the neighborhood where the code lives.

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks! But I can exclude that possibility for sure. It occures for multiple users in multiple browsers. It is definately a script (internal or external) embedded in the page. But I unfortunately have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: @Doug: This would kinda help to determinate the origin. But this is still very very time consuming since there are lots of scripts embedded. Even if I could determine that it's not from a blocked external script there would be soo many internal scripts to go through so I was hoping there would be an easier way to find the source. But it's a good point. Thank you! :)

Comment: you can speed it up with a faked binary search of files (remove half -- if the problem persists, then you know it exists in the half remaining. restore and remove the half of the half and so on ...) it's definitely not graceful and very brute force. but it's the best I can come up with, at the moment.

Comment: to my knowledge, there isn't a way to track what JS has changed an element ... and there's a wide variety of ways to create this effect, that it'd be hard to even guess what the exact code would have been to trigger it (if its not obfusticated)

Comment: So do a text search on the word that is added?